# Conditional expectation of $\mathbb{E}(X - Y | (X, Y)\in\mathcal{A})$

Tags: random-variable, uniform-distribution, conditional-expectation

Given two independent random variables $X \sim \mathcal{U}[-1,5]$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{U}[-5,5]$, what is $$\mathbb{E}\{Y - X | X \le 1, Y > X, Y \in [-1,1] \}\,?$$

I managed to compute the respective probability

$$ \mathbb{P}\{ X \le 1, Y > X, Y \in [-1,1] \} = \mathbb{P}(X \le 1) \mathbb{P}(Y > X) \mathbb{P}(Y \in [-1,1]) = 1/3 * 1/2 * 1/5 = 1/30$$

How do I continue from there?

Comment: The second equation for the conditioning event is wrong: this is not the product of the probabilities. If this is an homework, please use the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) flag.

Comment: It's not homework; I'm trying to understand what's going on in a paper I'm currently reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it happens, this event
$$
\mathcal{A}=\left\{X\le 1\,,\,Y>X\,,\,-1\le Y\le 1\right\}
$$
has indeed probability $1/30$ (but not because the decomposition used in the question is always true!):
\begin{align*} \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A}) &= \int_{-1}^1 \int_{\max\{-1,x\}}^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{6}\frac{\text{d}y}{10}\\  &= \frac{1}{60}\int_{-1}^1 \left(1-\max\{-1,x\}\right) \text{d}x\\ &= \frac{1}{60} \int_{-1}^1 (1-x) \text{d} \\ &= \frac{1}{60} \frac{4-0}{2} = \frac{1}{30}\,.\end{align*}
The conditional expectation involves the numerator integral
\begin{align*} \int_{-1}^1 \int_{\max\{-1,x\}}^1 (x-y) \frac{\text{d}x}{6}\frac{\text{d}y}{10} &= \frac{1}{60}\int_{-1}^1 \left\{x(1-x)-\frac{1-x^2}{2}\right\} \text{d}x\\ &= \frac{-1}{120} \int_{-1}^1 (1-x)^2  \text{d}x\\ &= \frac{-1}{120} \frac{2^3 -0}{3} = \frac{-1}{45}\,.\end{align*}
Hence
$$\mathbb{E}[X-Y|\mathcal{A}]=\dfrac{-2}{3}\,.$$

Comment: Why do you divide by $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{A})$ to obtain the final result? I thought that EV involves some multiplication with $P$, not a division.

Comment: @bonifaz: For any event $A$ with $P(A)>0$, one has $\mathbb{E}[Z\mid A]=\mathbb{E}[Z\mathbf{1}_A]/P(A)$.